# changing the colour of a listview item

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

i have a listview that contains info about my customers. it's basically a list of users who have booked jobs. the listview uses firebase database as its source. and it connects to a node called Bookings. it then has the userid as its Key.

```
{
  "Bookings": {
    "User-Id appears here": {
      "Fullname": "Name Appears here",
      "Date": "",
      "Valet Type": "",
      "Car Model": "",
      "CustomerID": "",
      "Approved": ""
    }
  }
}
```

The Approved node can be one of 3 values "Not Approved", "Approved", "Canceled"
depending on the Approved value i wanted to change the colour of the listview item that contains the data. I have managed to get the listview to change colour when the item is Clicked but i want it to stay that colour unless The "Approved" node says otherwise.

here is the code i have so far which makes it change when the item is clicked.

```
bookingsref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                date = snapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString();
                name = snapshot.child("Fullname").getValue().toString();
                valet = snapshot.child("ValetType").getValue().toString();
                model = snapshot.child("VehicleModel").getValue().toString();
                customerid = snapshot.child("UserId").getValue().toString();

                confirm = snapshot.child("Approved").getValue().toString();
                ApproveArray.add(confirm);
                bookingID.add(customerid);

booking_info_minor.add(date + "\n" + "Name: "+ name + "\n"+"Valet Type: "+valet + "\n" +"Model: " + model + "\n"+"Customer ID: "+ customerid );

                adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bookings .this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,booking_info_minor);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String c = bookingID.get(position).toString();
                        confirm = ApproveArray.get(position);


                        Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Booking_details.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString( "UserId",c);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        listColour(position,confirm);


                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void listColour(int pos,String confirm){
    Log.i("Conf",confirm);
    if (confirm.equals("Approved")){
        lv = findViewById(R.id.templist);
        lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundResource(R.color.approved);
    }
    if (confirm.equals("Not Approved")) {
        lv = findViewById(R.id.templist);
        lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundResource(R.color.not_approved);
    }

    if (confirm.equals("Canceled")) {
        lv = findViewById(R.id.templist);
        lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundResource(R.color.canceled);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `Override` ArrayAdapter's `getView` and make appropriate changes like below:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bookings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, booking_info_minor) {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        String confirm = ApproveArray.get(position);

        switch (confirm) {
            case "Approved":
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.approved);
                break;
            case "Not Approved":
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.not_approved);
                break;
            case "Canceled":
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.canceled);
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: ive used a combo of both answers. i used an adapter and then in getview ive added your code thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just in your adapters `getView()` method, call a function like your `listColour(position,confirm);` where you are setting texts to your list items views. For more detail add your list adapter code.

Comment: is that my problem ive just used the basic adapter for my listview?

Comment: adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bookings .this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,booking_info_minor);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Oo.. then use a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

i ended up using a combo of the answers above i ended up making a base adapter for my list then added a switch to allow the choice for the approved node inside the get view.

in my bookings activity i had to add a few more arrays in the onDataChange method

```
  Name_Array.add(name);
                Date_Array.add(date);
                Valet_Array.add(valet);
                Model_Array.add(model);
                CustomerId.add(customerid);
                ApproveArray.add(confirm);

                final String[] name = Name_Array.toArray(new String[Name_Array.size()]);
                final String[] approve = ApproveArray.toArray(new String[ApproveArray.size()]);
                String[] date = Date_Array.toArray(new String[Date_Array.size()]);
                String[] valet = Valet_Array.toArray(new String[Valet_Array.size()]);
                final String[] model = Model_Array.toArray(new String[Model_Array.size()]);
                final String[] customerid = CustomerId.toArray(new String[CustomerId.size()]);

                ArrayAdapter apkData = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), name, valet, model, customerid, date, approve);
```

then my base adpater looked like this

```
public class ArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String[] Name, ValetType, Model;
    String[] CustomerId,Date,Approved;
    Context mContext;
    ImageView report;
    TextView tvname,tvdate,tvvalet,tvmodel,tvid,tvapproved;

    public ArrayAdapter() {
        Name = null;
        ValetType = null;
        Model = null;
        Date = null;
        CustomerId = null;
        Approved = null;
    }

    public ArrayAdapter(Context c, String[] name, String[] valettype, String[] model,String[]customerid,String[] date,String[] approved) {
        Name = name;
        ValetType = valettype;
        Model = model;
        this.mContext = c;
        Date = date;
        CustomerId =customerid;
        Approved = approved;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Name.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View row;
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
         else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        tvname =  row.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvdate =  row.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
        tvvalet =  row.findViewById(R.id.tv_valet);
        tvapproved = row.findViewById(R.id.tvconf);
        tvmodel =  row.findViewById(R.id.tv_model);
        tvid =  row.findViewById(R.id.tvid);

        tvdate.setText(Date[position]);
        tvname.setText(Name[position]);
        tvvalet.setText(ValetType[position]);
        tvapproved.setText(Approved[position]);
        tvmodel.setText(Model[position]);
        tvid.setText(CustomerId[position]);
        String approve =Approved[position];

        switch (approve) {
            case "Approved":
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.approved);
                break;
            case "Not Approved":
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.not_approved);
                break;
            case "Canceled":
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.canceled);
                break;

        }
        return (row);
    }
```

}